# What 's up with the Jobs section?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just noticed a *Jobs* section:

[image]

As it says, I get a *page not found*. I'm reasonably certain I have a [Stack Overflow Careers profile](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/info/620658). So, what is *Jobs* for, and how can I access it?

The [feature request to extend Careers to us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251063/270345) is [status-deferred](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred).

It's even present on beta sites:

[image]

Comment: O.o this is new (like not older than 10 minutes).

Comment: @kos Looks like a bug.

Comment: Yeah probably, it's everywhere. I'd be surprised if they extended it to all sites. Not sure if it even makes sense to have it on certain sites.

Comment: OK, I'll vote to close, and post again on [meta.se].

Comment: Looking into it..

Comment: That doesn't make it off-topic.. They are aware of the problem. You can repost if you really want though.

Comment: @Seth no, anywhere will do, but, as I understand it, they get alerted on bugs or feature requests, not general discussion or support questions.

Comment: @Shog9 out of curiosity, what was it?

Comment: Someone forgot to limit this to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't see it.

Comment: @StarOS Read the comment above yours.

Comment: @muru OK. I've read it but i thought it was still there, now i know it's been removed.